Does $f'(x)^\top H x \geq -f'(x)^\top f'(x)$ for a convex function?
Given a convex function $f(x): \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$, let $g(x) = x^\top f'(x)$. I want to prove that
$$
f'(x)^\top g'(x) \geq 0
\tag1
\label{eq1}
$$
for all $x$.
Here is how I proceed. Differentiating $g(x)$, we get
$$g'(x) = f'(x) + H x \tag2$$
where $H \equiv f''(x)$ is the Hessian, which is positive semi-definite for all $x$ in this case. Left multiplying by $f'(x)$, we get,
$$f'(x)^\top g'(x) = f'(x)^\top f'(x) + f'(x)^\top H x \tag3$$
At this point, I have translated my problem to be equivalent to showing that
$$f'(x)^\top H x \geq -f'(x)^\top f'(x) \tag4$$
This is where my knowledge hits a boundary. How to proceed further? For simple cases, such as when $f(x) = \frac12 x^\top x$, the above inequality is obvious. However, what about general cases? Should the above inequality hold for any convex function?

Edit
As the answer below points out, this is not true in general, using a simple case. However, if we focus only on the angle between $x$ and $f'(x)$, so that now,
$$h(x) := \frac{x^\top f'(x)}{\Vert x\Vert \Vert f'(x) \Vert} \tag5$$
It appears intuitively that $|h(x)|$ should be maximized if we move towards the minima.
$$\lim_{x \to x^*} |h(x)| = 1 \tag6$$
I couldn't find a 1D or 2D example that violates this idea. Can we prove it?

You really should ask another question, that is a fairly significant change to the original.

done. Linking for xref.

Best to try this sort of thing with $n=1$ first.
Try $f(x) = {1 \over 2} (x-\alpha)^2$. Then $f'(x) = x-\alpha$, $g(x) = x(x-\alpha), g'(x) = 2x-\alpha$. Hence we have
$f'(x)g'(x) = (x-\alpha)(2x-\alpha)$ and note that we have $f'({3 \over 4} \alpha)g'({3 \over 4} \alpha) = -{1 \over 8} \alpha^2$.

Thanks for the clarifying answer. It seems to me that the magnitude of $x$ plays an important role.  What if, instead, we focus only on the angle between $x$ and $f'(x)$? Please see my edit. Thanks.
